# Erro ao fazer chamadas métodos de uma classe através de outra

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Minha aplicação crasha quando eu escrevo esse código abaixo, estou tentando estanciar a Classe Login na Classe Cadastro e acessar os métodos da classe Login através da classe Cadastro.

```
    ca.getLogar().setLogin(logCad.getText().toString());
    ca.getLogar().setSenha(senhaCad.getText().toString());
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de resolver isso ? Esses são os método de acesso e atributos lá na classe cadastro para classe login

```
private LoginClasse logar;

    public LoginClasse getLogar() {
        return logar;
    }

    public void setLogar(LoginClasse logar) {
        this.logar = logar;
    }
```

Classe Login

```
    public class LoginClasse {
    
        private String login;
        private String senha;
    
    
    
        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }
    
        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }
    
        public String getSenha() {
            return senha;
        }
    
        public void setSenha(String senha) {
            this.senha = senha;
        }
    }
```

Classe Cadastro

```
public class CadastroClasse {

    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String tel;
    private String end;
    private String cep;
    private String email;

    private LoginClasse logar;

    public LoginClasse getLogar() {
        return logar;
    }

    public void setLogar(LoginClasse logar) {
        this.logar = logar;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Método Cadastrar que é responsável pelo problema

```
    public void Cadastrar(View view)
        {
            CadastroClasse ca=new CadastroClasse();
        
    
            ca.getLogar().setLogin(logCad.getText().toString());
            ca.getLogar().setSenha(senhaCad.getText().toString());
            ca.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
            ca.setCpf(cpf.getText().toString());
            ca.setTel(tel.getText().toString());
            ca.setEnd(end.getText().toString());
            ca.setCep(cep.getText().toString());
            ca.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    
            startActivity(new Intent(Cadastro.this,MainActivity.class));
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua classe Cadastro tem o atributo  private LoginClasse logar; porém você não inicializa ele em nenhum momento. Com isso, você está tentando chamar o setLogin de uma variável que não foi inicializada, e isso acaba gerando um erro.

Para resolver isso você poderia, modificar a sua main e chamar setLogar da classe cadastro passando um objeto LoginClasse, exemplo:

```
public void Cadastrar(View view)
        {
            CadastroClasse ca=new CadastroClasse();
        
            ca.setLogar(LoginClasse());//linha adicionada por mim
            ca.getLogar().setLogin(logCad.getText().toString());
            ca.getLogar().setSenha(senhaCad.getText().toString());
            ca.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
            ca.setCpf(cpf.getText().toString());
            ca.setTel(tel.getText().toString());
            ca.setEnd(end.getText().toString());
            ca.setCep(cep.getText().toString());
            ca.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    
            startActivity(new Intent(Cadastro.this,MainActivity.class));
    
        }
```

Outra forma seria instanciar essa classe no construtor da classe CadastroClasse, exemplo

```
public class CadastroClasse {

    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String tel;
    private String end;
    private String cep;
    private String email;

    private LoginClasse logar;
    
    public CadastroClasse(){
        logar = LoginClasse()
    }
   
    //resto do codigo
```

Fazendo uma dessas formas você estará inicializando a variável logar e conseguirá acessar os métodos da classe LoginClasse.